# Technical Question On Page 17 of Yitang Zhang's Paper

Tags: number-theory

I was reading through "Bounded Gaps Between Primes", by Yitang Zhang(The link is [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.308.998&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). On   page 17, he says that The contribution from the terms with $q \geq D_0$ above is $\ll D_0^{-1}L^B$. I couldn't  understand why this is.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would be nice that you use Latex to type your question. You have a basic tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also it would be friendly to rewrite the context. I doubt that many will make the effort to read the article if on your side you don't make the effort to help us.

Comment: After quick examination, none of $D_0, \mathscr L, B$ are defined near the passage in question.  I don't think it's reasonable to ask people to read the entire paper to sort out one technical question.  Can you phrase the question in a clear, self-contained, way?

Comment: There is nothing special in that $O(D_0^{-1} \log^B x)$ estimate for some $B$, he takes the previously shown obvious bounds of each term